# Add `if` condition to ActiveAdmin batch_batch destroy action but use default action behavior otherwise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm trying to add conditional display of the default ActiveAdmin :destroy batch action so that the option only displays based on user role.  The problem is that adding the `if` property to the `batch_action` method call seems to disable the default behavior and instead rely on a block.  For example:

```
batch_action :destroy, if: proc { authorization_logic_here }
```

properly shows/hides the batch action based on the user role but if the action is displayed it doesn't do anything.  I can supply a block with instructions to how to handle the destroy request but I'd prefer to not have to re-invent the wheel every time I need to do this.  Is there a way to tell the `batch_action` call to conditionally display but otherwise use default behaviors for the `:destroy` action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. You will have to implement the destroy yourself. Here is an example:

```
batch_action :destroy, confirm: 'Beware', if: proc { true } do |ids|
  q = resource_class.where(id: ids).map(&:destroy)
  redirect_to collection_path, notice: "#{q.count} destroyed"
end
```